# Ideals in commutative noetherian rings with unique prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring with $1$ having only one prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$. It follows that $\mathfrak{P}^n = 0$ for some integer $n$. Can we say that every proper ideal in $R$ is a power of $\mathfrak{P}$?

Comment: $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{P}$ are supposed to be the same letter I guess?

Comment: See mccarty book multiplicative ideal theory

Comment: Is $\mathfrak B$ nonzero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

No. Take a look at $F_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.

The answer is affirmative, however, if $\mathfrak{P}$ is principal. Add that hypothesis and try to prove that the other nonzero ideals are powers of it.